# ExtJS ComboBox list with icons and text based on store data

Tags: extjs, combobox, store, extjs5

I have a `combobox`, which is feeded from a store with information of an `iconCLS` and a text.

And i would like for it to show both the icon and the text, as shown in the example [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihc5i.png)
I was able to add them to the dropdown, but after selecting a value, the icon disappears.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.customer-info-sub-chooser-gold-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('images/customer-info/sub-chooser-gold-icon.png');
    content: url('images/customer-info/sub-chooser-gold-icon.png');
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: 55px 2px;
}
```

Ext:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
minHeight: 30,
name: 'contactType',
padding: '5 0 0 10',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
queryMode: 'local',
isEditable: true,
allowBlank: false,
disabled: false,
columnWidth: 1 / 4,
store: Ext.create('Components.contacts.contactComponent.store.ChooserStore'),
    listConfig: {
        //test
        getInnerTpl: function (displayField) {
            return '<img src="customer-info-sub-chooser-gold-icon" class="icon"/> {' + displayField + '}';
        }
    }
```

Store

```
Ext.define('Components.contacts.contactComponent.store.ChooserStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Processes.customerInfo.model.ComboBox',
    autoDestroy: true,
    proxy: "memory",
    data: [
        {id: 'sub-chooser-gold-icon', name: "Chooser"},
        {id: 'sub-chooser-grey-icon', name: "Sub-chooser"}
    ]
});
```

ComboBox Model:

```
Ext.define('Processes.customerInfo.model.ComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
  ]
});
```

Can anyone give me some help?

Note: I have to insert the icon through the `cls"customer-info-sub-chooser-gold-icon"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15m5)

You are almost there, just use [`tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-cfg-tpl) (`Ext.view.BoundListView` is picker of the `xtype: 'combo'`) config instead of [`getInnerTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.view.BoundList-method-getInnerTpl), like this:

```
listConfig: {
    tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="{x-boundlist-item}"><img src="{icon}" class="icon"/>{name}</div></tpl>'
}
```

Also read about using of [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) in general.

Comment: So, should i call that method with afterRender on my combobox?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in `afterrender` event handler.